# Imperial levels time increases?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I noticed that the imperial level items take a lot longer to build all of a sudden this morning on windows phone.  Did that happen on the other platforms, too?

Also, it seems that the rewards for creating cooling coils are insufficient to the cost of the cooling coils.....

Comment: It seems to me that it was more-so balanced if anything. Unless I'm mistaken, it appears some items have decreased costs now while others have increased costs.

Comment: Good point - a few of the cheaper items got cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened with iOS.  The Imperial item build times are generally longer and not as clustered.  That is, previously there were a bunch of different items with the same times (55 minutes, 1:05, 1:25, ...) and now they are more spread out, including some rather long ones.  The longest are in the Superlaser Ray level (5:20 for "Cooling Coil", and 8:40 for "Blaster Rifle") which were both previously around 2 hours.

In the update two major revisions ago, the Superlaser Ray was also the longest, with 5:20 for the single item available then.  So it appears that they have reverted to those times for the first item, with longer times for the newer second items.

Edit: the costs associated to Imperial item building have also changed, apparently in proportion to the time required.

Second edit: the costs have changed again with the most recent update (data 1.4) of about Feb 23rd 2014, and the costs and times are now less extreme than they were for a while there.

Comment: Is this still true for you?  I hadn't played the game for a few days and just opened it (no updates in App Store) and all of the prices and times seem unchanged... did it revert back to the shorter times?  I don't have any items that take more than 2 hours.