# How are imperial product prices calculated?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I recently noticed a huge increase in the price of the Combat droid in the Imperial Lab.
It happened over the night after completing one.

It jumped from a little more than 1 hour (around 1200 credits) to complete to 5 hours and 11000 credits!

It is very annoying because the imperial missions that were active at that time require a ton of those. The reward will not cover the costs (by a long shot).

What could have caused this huge increase?

Comment: Have prices reverted for you?  I just opened the app and the prices and times were the original, lower ones with nothing taking more than 2 hours or so.  I hadn't opened the game in a few days, so I'd not noticed the prices/times going up personally.

Comment: No they have not. :(

Comment: Update: apparently they have reverted to their initial value, making completing missions profitable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a new update — according to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/157227/66181), it partially reverted to an earlier behavior.

**Edit:** I'll quote that answer about how prices are calculated:

> the costs associated to Imperial item building have also changed, apparently in proportion to the time required.
>
> It is very annoying because the imperial missions that were active at that time require a ton of those. The reward will not cover the costs (by a long shot).

Some subsequent missions are no better, which is indeed annoying (cannot show an example now).
However, skipping them costs 10 bux, which is also a lot.

For me, this seems to have started with the update which introduced the new mission system, together with the promotion for imperial medals (though I didn't notice the prices were so high, so maybe it was not the case then).

**Edit 2**: the prices seem to have dropped back to "normal" (around ~1500/2000 bucks tops).